# Internet Explorer background-color hover problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a strange Problem with table formating using IE 7.

My table looks like this:

[image: Correct table rendering]

In IE, when using border-collapse, the borders don't get displayed correctly. That's why I used this fix:

```
.table-vmlist td { border-top: 1px solid black; }
td.col-vm-status, tr.row-details td { border-left: 1px solid black; }
td.col-vm-rdp, tr.row-details td { border-right: 1px solid black; }
.table-vmlist { border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

When hovering over the row, it gets highlighted with CSS:

[image: Table highlighting]

```
.table-vmlist tr.row-vm { background-color: #A4C3EF; }
.table-vmlist tr.row-vm:hover { background-color: #91BAEF; }
```

Now, in IE 7, when moving the mouse from the top to the bottom of the list, every row gets highlighted correctly and no problems happen. But if I move my mouse pointer from the bottom of the list to the top, every second row seems to loose the border.

[image: IE7 Bug]

Can someone explain what the problem is, and how to solve it?

This is my markup:

```
<tr class="row-vm">
    <td class="col-vm-status status-1"><img title="Host Down" alt="Down" src="/Technik/vm-management/img/hoststatus_1.png"></td>
    <td class="col-vm-name">V1-VM-1</td>
    <td class="col-vm-stati">
        <img title="Ping" alt="Ping status" src="/Technik/vm-management/img/servicestatus_3.png">
        <img title="CPU" alt="CPU status" src="/Technik/vm-management/img/servicestatus_3.png">
        <img title="RAM" alt="RAM status" src="/Technik/vm-management/img/servicestatus_3.png">
        <img title="C:\ Diskspace" alt="Disk space status" src="/Technik/vm-management/img/servicestatus_3.png">
    </td>
    <td class="col-vm-owner">kus</td>
    <td class="col-vm-purpose">Citrix Testserver</td>
    <td class="col-vm-ip">-</td>
    <td class="col-vm-uptime">-</td>
    <td class="col-vm-rdp">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* VM-Tabelle formatieren */
.table-vmlist { border-collapse: collapse; }
.table-vmlist tr { border: 1px solid black; }
.table-vmlist tr.row-header { border: none; }
.table-vmlist tr.row-vm { background-color: #A4C3EF; }
.table-vmlist tr.row-vm:hover { background-color: #91BAEF; }
.table-vmlist th { text-align: left; }
.table-vmlist td {  }
.table-vmlist th, table td { padding: 2px 0px; }

/* Spaltenbreite der VM-Tabelle festlegen */
.table-vmlist #col-status { width: 25px; }
.table-vmlist #col-stati { width: 90px; }
.table-vmlist #col-owner { width: 90px; }
.table-vmlist #col-ip { width: 100px; }
.table-vmlist #col-uptime { width: 70px; }
.table-vmlist #col-rdp { width: 25px; }
.table-vmlist tr.row-details td { padding: 0px 10px; }

/* Kein Rahmen um verlinkte Bilder */
a img { border-width: 0px; }

/* Für Einschaltknopf Hand-Cursor anstatt normalen Pfeil anzeigen */
td.status-1 img { cursor: pointer; }
img.ajax-loader { margin-left: 2px; }
```

IE fix:

```
.table-vmlist td { border-top: 1px solid black; }
td.col-vm-status, tr.row-details td { border-left: 1px solid black; }
td.col-vm-rdp, tr.row-details td { border-right: 1px solid black; }
.table-vmlist { border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but the :hover selector may not be working on ie7 depending on your DOCTYPE. More info here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/619c4492-ab7b-4a8e-b911-5fed8aa49457/

Comment: I think this doesn't have to do with the doctype. I used the doctype for "XHTML Transitional", but even when I change it to HTML, the bug persists.

It works perfectly with IE8.

Comment: that's the problem. it shouldn't be transitional, it should be strict.
try this:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Thanks Corroded, I was having a similar problem for the past few hours with a custom CSS dropdown menu and it was simply the doctype that you specified above that fixed it.

Comment: I tried both the "HTML strict" doctype provided by you as well as "XHTML strict", but both of them didn't help. I tried it both in IE8 with compatibility (IE7) mode as well as directly with the IE7 rendering engine (without quirks mode)...